# Is every set that's a union of two sets disconnected?

Tags: general-topology

I'm curious about the definition of disconnected and I'm sure this can't be right. But let's say that $S= A \cup B$, then isn't $S$ automatically disconnected? Since I can re-write It as $(S \cap C) \cup (S \cap D)$ with $C=A$ and $D=B$? This is a circular definition since it basically uses an identity about unions and intersection, but is my understanding of disconnected totally off? Or is this just a trivial case we toss aside? I'm a tad confused here.

Comment: What if $A$ and $B$ are not disjoint?

Comment: What if $A = B$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $A=[0,1]$ and $B=[1,2]$; both sets are connected, and $A\cup B=[0,2]$, which is also connected. Let $A$ be the set of irrational numbers and $B$ the set of rational numbers; then both $A$ and $B$ are totally disconnected, but $A\cup B=\Bbb R$ is connected.

In order for $S$ not to be connected, you must be able to write it as a disjoint union of non-empty sets that are both relatively open in $S$: $S=U\cup V$, say, where $U\ne\varnothing\ne V$, $U\cap V=\varnothing$, and $U\cap\operatorname{cl}V=V\cap\operatorname{cl}U=\varnothing$. Notice the requirements: $U$ and $V$ are non-empty, they’re disjoint, their union is $S$, and each is a relatively open subset of $S$. All of these conditions must be met in order for $U$ and $V$ to be a separation of $S$.

Comment: Okay could you point me in the right way about proving that? If those conditions are all met S= U u V and U and V are disjoint, I don't need to the know the exact proof but just the gist of it. Also why I'm slightly confused about relatively open, is there an intuitive sense for why that's needed? Thank you for your help by the way, you guys are all life savers!

Comment: @Roger: That’s actually just the usual definition, so there’s nothing to prove unless you’ve been given some other definition as a starting point. // Do you have any intuitive sense of why we’d want to consider $[0,2]$ connected but $[0,1)\cup(1,2]$ disconnected?

Comment: Is it because the latter two sets aren't closed? So they don't contain all their boundary points, I'm not really sure.

Comment: @Roger: The sets $[0,1)$ and $(1,2]$ **are** relatively closed subsets of $[0,1)\cup(1,2]$. Indirectly, that’s why $[0,1)\cup(1,2]$ is not connected: if they were relatively closed, then, since they’re complementary in $[0,1)\cup(1,2]$, they’d also be relatively open and hence constitute a separation of $[0,1)\cup(1,2]$. But that’s not the kind of answer for which I was looking. I’m asking whether it makes any kind of **intuitive** sense to you that $[0,1)\cup(1,2]$ is not connected, while $[0,2]$ is connected.

Comment: No, it doesn't really make any intutive sense right now. I'm going to keep studying and see if I can understand why, maybe seeing more proofs about disconnected sets will help.

Comment: I think I have an idea that's not connected since the 1 is not contained in the set, it's like a country's border that somehow that is missing at one point. That's weird but I think I get it. Thank you!

Comment: @Roger: See if this helps. $[0,1)\cup(1,2]$ has a natural break between $[0,1)$ and $(1,2]$. For instance, no sequence in $[0,1)$ can converge to any point in $(1,2]$, and *vice versa*. You can’t split $[0,2]$ that way: no matter how you split it into two non-empty sets, there are sequences in one set that converge to points in the other, so the two sets are somehow tied together.

Comment: Ahh yes! That makes sense, that's why you can split the rationals with pi! Got it!

Answer (score 1):

Disconnectedness requires also that $A,B$ are disjoint.

Comment: Not only disjoint. Both open (or closed). $[0,2]=[0,1]\cup (1,2]$ is connected.

Comment: I didn't say "only"; this is necessary not sufficient. I was highlighting the salient point. One can always write $S=S\cup S$ where $S$ is open in $S$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the topic is topology, I'm interpreting the question is follows: If $X$ is a topological space and $A,B\subseteq X$, is $A\cup B$ always disconnected?

The answer is no, for two reasons. The first is trivial, simply if $A$ and $B$ are not disjoint, then their union may be connected (e.g., take $X=\mathbb R$, A=B=[0,1]). More interestingly, there are famous examples of two disjoint sets whose union is connected, for instance take $X=\mathbb R$, $A=(0,1]$, and $B=\{0\}$. A more interesting example is for instance [the topologist's since curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve).

Answer (score 0):

$S$ is disconnected if it is the union of two *disjoint*, *open*, non-empty subsets $A$ and $B$.

So if $S = A \cup B$ for *some* $A$ and $B$, it could still be connected because $A$ and $B$ are not disjoint or one of $A$ or $B$ is not open.

**Example 1:** If $S = (0, 1)$, we can write $S = A \cup B$ where $A = (0, 3/4)$ and $B = (1/4, 1)$. $A$ and $B$ are both open but not disjoint, so this doesn't contradict the fact that $(0,1)$ is connected.

**Example 2:** Again take $S = (0,1)$, but this time take $A = (0,1/2)$ and $B = [1/2, 1)$. Then $S = A \cup B$ and $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, but the problem here is that $B$ is not open in $(0,1)$.

Comment: I see I guess I'm kind of struggling in the more abstract sense, because on some intuitive level I always think that every set can be written as a union so every set is disconnected almost. I think I'm starting to understand it, thank you for your help.